# Not able to access apoc.periodic.commit API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When i try to use the below API,

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
match (node)
with node, limit {limit}
DETACH DELETE node
RETURN count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

I am getting the following warning:

> WARNING: apoc.periodic.commit is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict procedures you can trust with access to database internals.

I have the following settings in neo4j.conf

```
dbms.directories.plugins=/home/srangara/work/Neo4j/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.2/plugins/
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
```

Plugins directory contains the following:

```
-rwxr-x---  1 srangara calypto_eng 7271085 Feb 20 22:02 apoc-3.3.0.1-all.jar
```

Do I need any other dependency plugins. If so what are they and how to get them?

Comment: have you restarted Neo4j after editing the conf file?

Comment: also, are you using other plugins than APOC, like Neo4h graph algorithms?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the Neo4j.

Comment: No I am not using any other plugins.

Comment: Is apoc.periodic.commit depends on any other .jar files. At present i have only  apoc-3.3.0.1-all.jar in my plugins directory.
Or
Do i need to unrestirct anything other than apoc.* ?

Comment: This problem went away when i move to cypher-shell ( I was using neo4j-shell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away when i moved to  cypher-shell from neo4j-shell